# How to remove fields from a TypeScript interface via extension

Tags: typescript

Let's say there's an interface that I don't have control over:

```
interface Original {
  name: string;
  size: number;
  link: SomeType;
}
```

I want to extend this interface, but actually *remove* `link` so I end up with a new interface that is effectively:

```
interface OriginalLite {
  name: string;
  size: number;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use [mapped](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types) and [conditional](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) types to achieve this.  Usually we call what you're trying to do `Omit`:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

(for TS3.5+, the `Omit` utility type [is included in the standard library](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type), so you don't have to define it yourself anymore)

So `Omit<T, K>` is basically the same as `T` but with none of the properties in `K`.  You can do the following to make a new `interface` called `OriginalLite` which is missing only `link`:

```
interface OriginalLite extends Omit<Original, 'link'> {}
```

Note that you are *not extending* `Original`.  That's because to "extend" in TypeScript means to make a type more specific (a.k.a. "narrowing"), but in your case what you are doing is making it less specific (a.k.a. "widening").  So that's why `extends Original` does not appear in that definition.  I assume that's okay with you.

Let's test it:

```
declare const originalLite: OriginalLite;
originalLite.name; // string
originalLite.size; // number
originalLite.link; // error, property 'link' does not exist on type 'OriginalLite'
```

Looks good.

Comment: For people looking to exclude multiple properties, that would be: `interface OriginalLite extends Omit<Original, 'link'|'size'> {}`

Comment: Here is a list of all Utility Types: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: @jcalz based on op's requirements just `type OriginalLite = Omit<Original, "link">` is fine? is he wrong in extending into another interface without additional properties?

Comment: If they don't care about the difference between a `type` alias and an `interface` (and usually you don't really care), yes, that's fine.  And since `Omit` was added to the standard library [in TS3.5](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-5.html#the-omit-helper-type) there's no need to implement it ourselves anymore.

Answer (score 9):

Sample of omitting multiple unwanted properties from a type, and adding new custom properties.

```
type UnwantedKeys = "key1" | "key2"

interface MyNewType extends Omit<Original, <UnwantedKeys>> {
  newProp1: string
  newProp2: number
}
```

Comment: Reference: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys

Comment: What's different from the accepted answer ?

Comment: I’m to the point.

Answer (score 9):

Just to add: if you don't have a list of keys you want to remove but only interface you can use `keyof` to get a list of keys and omit them.

Example:

```js
interface RemoveThoseKeys {
  removeMe1: unknown
  removeMe2: unknown
}

interface AllKeys {
  keep1: unknown
  keep2: unknown
  removeMe1: unknown
  removeMe2: unknown
}

type KeysAfterRemoval = Omit<AllKeys, keyof RemoveThoseKeys>
```

If you instantiate an object with type `KeysAfterRemoval` and hit auto-completion in your IDE you should get only `keep1` and `keep2`.

[image: IDE autocompletion]