# Limit typescript interface to another interface

Tags: typescript

Given a typescript interface:

```
interface alpha {
  name?: string;
  age?: string;
  sign?: string;
}
```

I would like to create another interface that is confined to have a limited set of properties from another interface

```
interface beta {
  age?: string;
}
```

Is this possible?

If someone was to have:

```
interface beta {
  foo?: string;
}
```

I'd like it to be invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great answer here: [How to remove fields from a TypeScript interface via extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51804810/how-to-remove-fields-from-a-typescript-interface-via-extension)

So you make a "helper type" called e.g. `Omit` to omit certain properties from your interface:

```
type Omit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>
```

Likewise, you can also modify the properties of your existing interface, which can be useful many times:

```
type Readonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: T[P];
}
type Partial<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]?: T[P];
}
```

Also, sometimes it's easier to turn it around. Extend alpha from beta.

```
interface alpha extends beta {
  name?: string;
  sign?: string;
}

interface beta {
  age?: string;
}

const x: alpha = {
    name: "foo" // valid
}

const y: beta = {
    name: "where" // invalid
}
```